# JPA Many to One relationship

Tags: jpa

I am bit beginner on JPA and need some help on fetching the Many to One relationship in JPA.

I have below entities.

User which stores all user information . User extends Audiatable abstract class which is for holding auidt paramters like last modified date, creation date etc.

I am trying to add another fields as **lastUpdatedByUser** which should get fetched from **lastUpdatedBy** for which I amtrying to add Many-One relationship.
But the relation is not working somehow, am I doing something wrong here?

AuditableEntity.java

```
public abstract class AuditableEntity<T extends Entity<T, ID>, ID> implements Auditable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "cruserid")
private Long createdBy;


@Column(name = "crdate")
@Type(type = JpaConstants.TYPE_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
private LocalDateTime createdOn;

@Column(name = "chuserid")
private Long lastUpdatedBy;

@Column(name = "chdate")
@Type(type = JpaConstants.TYPE_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
private LocalDateTime lastUpdatedOn;

@Transient
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = User.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "usrId", referencedColumnName = "chuserid")
private User lastUpdatedByUser;
```

User.java

```
public class User extends AuditableEntity<User, Long> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "usrId")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "usrName")
private String name;

@Column(name = "loginame")
private String loginName;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Well, you marked the association with @Transient, which means that the field is not persistent and should be ignored by JPA.

And you also seem to have two different fields to store the same information: `lastUpdatedBy` and `lastUpdateByUser`. Remove the first one, and map the second one as

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "chuserid")
private User lastUpdatedByUser;
```

This tells that the association is a ManyToOne to the User entity (no need to specify the targetEntity since it's the type of the field), and that this association is materialized by the join column named "chuserid", in the auditable entity's table, and referencing the ID of the User entity (referencedColumnName is only useful when you use composite IDs, or when you reference an entity by a column which is the the ID)

Comment: Hi, thnx for the ans but problem is we can't remove lastUpdateBy....its already referred at lot of place in existing code..so we want to add a Transient field lastUpdateByUser just to save our purpose as of now...its kind of weired design but refractoring is on hold due to time constraint

Comment: If it's used only in read-only mode, you should be able to remove the map the lastUpdatedByUser as shown above, and mark the Column on `lastUpdateBy` as non insertable and non updatable.

Comment: Thnx again, it works as per ur last comment but unfortunately lastUpdateBy is not used only in read only mode...for each entity it will be called to update the userid who did the last updation.