# i want to exclude field in hibernate anotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have a question about hibernate anotation.
I have a BaseEntity.java and a model that named state.java who extende BaseEntity.java

```
BaseEntity.java.

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity<T> implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private T                   id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CreatedBy", nullable = true)
    private User                createdBy;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "subsite", nullable = true)
   private Subsite              subsite;
}
```

state.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="State")
public class State extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    @Column(name = "state", nullable = true)
    private String  state;

    @Column(name = "city", nullable = true)
    private String  city;
 }
```

what should I do when a program build my table in Database ,one field like subsite set in my parent class but donot set in my child class 
and hibernate ignore this field.

Comment: updateBy is there in table ?

Comment: add your user class

Comment: @atie please have a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38162978/3344829

Answer (score 1):

you might use `@Transient` annotation on `createdBy` attribute, But sinc you are using `@ManyToOne` annotation, this attirbute is referenced to another one so it cannot be done for your case, please refere to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696695/jpa-many-to-one-relationship) for more information.